# Scheduling Python to automate static tweets

Tags: python, schedule, tweets

Just written a short and simple Python script to post on Twitter. I'm having issues where after 30 minutes the tweet appears multiple times where it should only be posted once every half an hour. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

```
import random
import tweepy
import schedule
import time

from auth import consumer_secret, consumer_key, access_token_secret, access_token

twitter_auth_keys = {
    'consumer_secret': consumer_secret,
    'consumer_key': consumer_key,
    'access_token_secret': access_token_secret,
    'access_token': access_token
}


def main():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_key'],
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_secret']
    )
    auth.set_access_token(
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token'],
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token_secret']
    )
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    file = open('words.txt', 'r')
    random_word = random.choice(file.readlines())
    tweet = ('The %s tree.' % random_word.strip())
    api.update_status(status=tweet)
    print('Tweeted: %s' % tweet)

    schedule.every(30).minutes.do(main)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems recursive. You tell schedule to do `main` every 30 minutes, and main will also call schedule. Try separating them.

From the docs:

```
def job():
    print("I'm working...")


schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

What you are (sorta) doing:

```
def rec_job():
    print("I'm working...")
    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(rec_job)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rec_job()
```

You can separate your code like this:

```
def send_message():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_key'],
        twitter_auth_keys['consumer_secret']
    )
    auth.set_access_token(
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token'],
        twitter_auth_keys['access_token_secret']
    )
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    file = open('words.txt', 'r')
    random_word = random.choice(file.readlines())
    tweet = ('The %s tree.' % random_word.strip())
    api.update_status(status=tweet)
    print('Tweeted: %s' % tweet)


def main():
    schedule.every(30).minutes.do(send_message)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I've tried to implement it but now im not getting anything returning from the script. Do I need to pass information from one function to the other somehow, because I get an error when I try? I'm still very new to python. Thanks for your help so far!