# Schedule tweet with Python - Twitter API v2?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Is it possible to post tweets as 'scheduled' with Twitter API in Python? (my preference is Tweepy, but at this point, anything will do).

The solutions I have found, like [this](https://github.com/pattonwebz/ScheduledTweetBot), [this](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/schedule-tweets-with-python-for-a-job-search-website-75589b0a1229), [this](https://medium.com/@j.yanming/step-by-step-guide-scheduled-daily-tweet-with-python-45d4117e1d92), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482144/scheduling-python-to-automate-static-tweets), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104171/is-it-possible-to-schedule-a-tweet) are all doing the same thing: starting a loop or using other methods to schedule Python to then post the tweets live when the time is right.

This is not what I'm after, as this requires a computer running the script 24/7 (or at least when you want the tweets to go live)

What I want is a script that can, say, run in a few seconds, and schedule 5 tweets a day for the coming week, so then it's safe to turn off my computer, and the tweets will still fire.

Is this possible at all? Seems like basic functionality, but I found no hints either in the documentation or by googling.

Am I overlooking something?

thanks,

Comment: There's no public Twitter API for setting this up, so you will be dependent on some kind of external service that remains running somewhere, and posts the Tweets at the appointed time. You don't have to run such a thing on your computer, you can build something that runs on a cloud service like Heroku to do it for you.

Comment: Too bad, but thanks @AndyPiper, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The [twitter-api-client](https://github.com/trevorhobenshield/twitter-api-client) may be of help. You can loop through your data using:

```
account.schedule_tweet(var_containing_text, var_containing_date)
```

and send all your scheduled tweets in one brief session.  `var_containing_date` can be in user readable format "2023-05-08 22:30"

I personally used and tested it for twitter's API v1, though the developer specified applicability to v2 as well. You might want to check it out.